# Panic Coda 2.5.1 SFTP No longer connects "Could not connect to server _____. Failed to open file"

Tags: coda, sftp

Since upgrading to Yosemite, I'm unable to connect via SFTP to any site.

It allows me to open a terminal and connect... so the credentials are good.

- I have reinstalled Coda (including removing the Library files and using "app delete" to remove all references - then re-installing)
- I have performed a "repair permissions" from the disk utility
- I have added new sites to the site manager, and they all fail

Any ideas or suggestions?

here is a screenshot:

[image: (screenshot of error)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSH known hosts file had the wrong permissions (which were not fixed by "repair permissions" from the disk utility)

to fix, run the following in terminal:

```
sudo chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```